# Neo4j Load CSV Import Stalling

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After playing around with toy datasets, this was my first attempt to use data that is relevant for a project at work.  In short, after limping to get nearly all of my data into Neo4j, my last query simply stalled.  See the screenshot.

[image]

Note:  I was prototyping my queries by pasting them into the browser tool, but my longer term plan was to keep all of the commands in a `.cql` file that I could script on my workstation in order to perform nightly analyses.

To add context to my problem, I am prototyping on my macbook.

- 8gb ram
- 2.2 ghz intel core i7
- osx 10.9.5
- 2.2.0 community

The files I am processing (rows/columns).  I am not importing every column, it was just easier to keep my current datasets in check.

- Ability.csv = 3/1
- brm.csv = 276992/34
- cont.sv = 80093/17
- email chain.csv = 199143/34 (this is the only data I can't get in)
- email first last.csv = 77849/20
- recs.csv = 77962/20
- templates_topics.csv = 29/3
- templates.csv = 49/4
- topics.csv = 13/1
- vendors = 5/1

The only config options that I set manually for neo4j were in `neo4j-wrapper.conf` where I set `wrapper.java.initmemory` and `wrapper.java.maxmemory` to `4096`.  I did this after poking around to find similar problems.

I made these changes out of the gate because within the browser, I was getting error messages that the database was disconnected while processing my queries.

Lastly, because my data are work-related, I can't provide test data.  I can, however, link to my cypher queries.

[Constraint and LOAD CSV .cql file](https://gist.github.com/Btibert3/365fea161e831b389153)

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.  I am pretty confident this is user error on my end, but I have definitely hit the road with respect to what my next steps would be.

Comment: In your last LOAD CSV statement, you are using `Email:cid` as property while your constraint is on `Email:msgid`

Comment: Good catch, let me see how that goes.

Comment: This time I got the "database disconnected" warning in the browser when I attempted to commands starting on line 111 of the cypher.cql file.  Will running the file from the command line offer any performance improvements?

Comment: To close the loop, when I ran the entire script from the command line, after fixing the typo from copy/paste, I was able to get all of my data into the database.

Comment: You have a much better experience with the shell when importing data.

Comment: And always try try to run `EXPLAIN LOAD CSV ...` (without the periodic commit) to see what your query plans look like (e.g. not using indexes, eager pipe etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid eager loading in LOAD CSV. It doesn't respect PERIODIC COMMIT. See this [article](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) by Mark Needham for a thorough explanation.

Comment: I did reference that article a few times.  My first issue (prior to posting this) was that I was using `MERGE` without regard.  I thought I was getting better by using MATCH + MERGE, but I am sure that there are still areas to refactor.

Comment: Have you tried 'divide and conquer' with the script, you can probably identify which section is the offending one, and use EXPLAIN / PROFILE functionality for better understanding what's causing the problem. Try to (for example) segmenting node creation with relationships, this way you can probably remove the offending MERGE.

Answer (score 2):

I would split this one up, into creating nodes once and creating relationships (each) second:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/btibert/Dropbox/Projects/bentley-search-neo4j/data/templates.csv" AS row
WITH row
MATCH (r:Vendor {name:row.vendor})
WITH row, r
MERGE (p:Template {name:row.template_clean})
MERGE (v:Version {version:row.template_ver})
MERGE (p)-[:FROM_VERSION]->(v)
MERGE (p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(r);
```

As you can clearly see the **Eager** operation in the plan.

I mean it doesn't matter if you just have a few thousand rows. But if it goes towards many hundred thousand or millions then pulling all data in takes more memory.

```
+----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Operator |                        Identifiers |                                                                                          Other |
+----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    EmptyResult |                                    |                                                                                                |
| UpdateGraph(0) | anon[270], anon[301], p, r, row, v |                                                                                   MergePattern |
| UpdateGraph(1) |            anon[270], p, r, row, v |                                                                                   MergePattern |
| UpdateGraph(2) |                       p, r, row, v | MergeNode; row.template_clean; :Template(name); MergeNode; row.template_ver; :Version(version) |
|          Eager |                             r, row |                                                                                                |
|    SchemaIndex |                             r, row |                                                                      row.vendor; :Vendor(name) |
|        LoadCSV |                                row |                                                                                                |
+----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would probably change this into an `ON CREATE SET` variant for the non-key properties:
Also if you have multiple rows per student you can use `WITH DISTINCT toInt(row.pidm) as pidm, ....` to reduce the number of merges it has to run.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "recs.csv" AS row
WITH row
MERGE (s:Student {pidm:toInt(row.pidm)})
ON CREATE SET s.hash_pidm=toInt(row.hash_pidm), ....;
```

This one I'd split up into two statements, one for each relationship, otherwise you might get too many matches:
(And you don't need the `WITH`s in between)

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...recs.csv" AS row
WITH row
MATCH (s:Student {pidm: toInt(row.pidm)} )
MATCH (v:Vendor {name: row.vendor} )
MATCH (a:Ability {name: row.ability} )
WITH row, s, v, a
MERGE (s)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(v)
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_ABILITY]->(a);
```

would become:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...recs.csv" AS row
MATCH (s:Student {pidm: toInt(row.pidm)} )
MATCH (v:Vendor {name: row.vendor} )
MERGE (s)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(v);


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...recs.csv" AS row
MATCH (s:Student {pidm: toInt(row.pidm)} )
MATCH (a:Ability {name: row.ability} )
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_ABILITY]->(a);
```

Here I would also create the contacts on themselves. (Again with ON CREATE SET)
And do the student relationship in a separate statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "....cont.csv" AS row
MERGE (c:Contact {cid:row.cid}) ON CREATE SET ....;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...cont.csv" AS row
MATCH (s:Student {pidm:toInt(row.pidm)} )
MATCH (c:Contact {cid:row.cid})
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_CONTACT]->(c);
```

I would also split this one up into two statements:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...cont.csv" AS row
WITH row WHERE toInt(row.seqnum) = 1
MATCH (s:Student {pidm:toInt(row.pidm)}) 
MATCH (f:Contact {cid:row.first_cont})
MERGE (s)-[:FIRST]->(f);

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...cont.csv" AS row
WITH row WHERE toInt(row.seqnum) = 1
MATCH (s:Student {pidm:toInt(row.pidm)}) 
MATCH (l:Contact {cid:row.last_cont})
MERGE (s)-[:LAST]->(l);
```

Split this one up into E-Mail creation and then later connecting it to the student by msg-id:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "...brm.csv" AS row
MERGE (e:Email {msgid:row.msgid}) ON CREATE SET ... ;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/btibert/Dropbox/Projects/bentley-search-neo4j/data/brm.csv" AS row
MATCH (s:Student {pidm:toInt(row.pidm)}) 
MATCH (e:Email {msgid:row.msgid})
MERGE (s)-[:WAS_SENT]->(e);
```

HTH Michael